# Udev rules for USB mounting and Low Graphics Mode error

Tags: usb, xorg, login-screen, udev

I have a file containing the content bellow

```
KERNEL!="sd[a-z][0-9]", GOTO="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"  
# Import FS infos  
IMPORT{program}="/sbin/blkid -o udev -p %N"  
# Get a label if present, otherwise specify one  
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}!="", ENV{dir_name}="%E{ID_FS_LABEL}"  
ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="", ENV{dir_name}="usbhd-%k"  
# Global mount options  
ACTION=="add", ENV{mount_options}="relatime"  
# Filesystem-specific mount options  
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}=="vfat|ntfs", ENV{mount_options}="$env{mount_options},utf8,gid=100,umask=002"  
# Mount the device  
ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p /home/my_dir_name", RUN+="/bin/mount -o $env{mount_options} /dev/%k /home/my_dir_name"  
# Clean up after removal  
ACTION=="remove", ENV{dir_name}!="", RUN+="/bin/umount -l /home/my_dir_name", RUN+="/bin/rmdir /home/my_dir_name"  
# Exit  
LABEL="media_by_label_auto_mount_end"
```

And when I put it in `/etc/udev/rules.d/file.rules` , and restart the computer I have this error message:

`The system is running in low-graphics mode.`

Once I delete this file I can boot normally.
Has anyone any idea about how can I keep this file to mount each connected USB and be able to login without this error?

Comment: Try comment this line `ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p /home/my_dir_name", RUN+="/bin/mount -o $env{mount_options} /dev/%k /home/my_dir_name"` . If it works, try again without mount cmd just `ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/mkdir -p /home/my_dir_name"`

Comment: Did you eventually solve this ? _(or an answer get back to me with CBhihe)_